# How do I select a row from Jquery Datables and grab the id of the first column?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, datatables

I want to select a row and grab the Id from the first column in order to open page in a dialog window? Not sure if I need to add a plugin for the select row functionality.

Here is my current Jquery Datatables:

```
oArticleListTable = $("#" + $gridId).dataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "bJQueryUI": true,
             "bAutoWidth": false,
             "bServerSide": true,
             "oLanguage": { "sProcessing": "<div class='processing-div ui-state-focus w120 ui-corner-all'><div style='float:left;'><img src='content/images/ajax-loader.gif'></div><div style='float:left;margin:10px 5px;'>Loading...</div><div class='cleardiv'></div></div>" },
             "sAjaxSource": "Services/IVOOARInventoryService.svc/GetInventories",
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
             "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
             "sScrollX": "120%",
             //"sScrollXInner": "120%",
             "asStripClasses": ['even', 'odd ui-state-default'],
             "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
             "aoColumns": [
                     //base information
                     { "sTitle": "Case Id", "sClass": "id-column grid-cell"},
                     { "sTitle": "Status", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "OAR Type", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "Tax Period", "sClass": "grid-cell" },

                     //unique identifiers
                     { "sTitle": "OAR Number", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "TAMIS Case Number", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "TIN", "sClass": "grid-cell" },

                     //assignment data
                     { "sTitle": "Assigned IDRS Org Code", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "Assigned IDRS TE", "sClass": "grid-cell" },

                     //chronology 
                     { "sTitle": "Date Entered", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "Date Received", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "Requested Completion Date", "sClass": "grid-cell" },

                     //TAS metadata
                     { "sTitle": "TAS Expedite", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "TAS Criteria", "sClass": "grid-cell" },

                     //closing data
                     { "sTitle": "Disposal Reason", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "Disposal Date", "sClass": "grid-cell" },

                     //target renegotiation
                     { "sTitle": "Negotiation Type", "sClass": "grid-cell" },
                     { "sTitle": "Negotiated Completion Date", "sClass": "grid-cell" }
             ],
             "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
                 //determine the column to filter data on if chosen
                 var searchFilter;
                 $(oSettings.aoColumns).each(function (index, column) {
                     // see if this is a searchable column
                     if (column.bSearchable) {
                         // it is, see if we declared our filter already
                         if (searchFilter === undefined) {
                             //we havent this column is it for now
                             searchFilter = index;
                         } else {
                             //we have, and this is the 2nd searchable column so we're searching all
                             searchFilter = "-1";
                         }
                     }
                 });

                 if (searchFilter === undefined) {
                     //we didnt find a column declared to be searchable on the client side
                     //default to "all"
                     searchFilter = "-1";
                 }

                 aoData.push({ "name": "filterSelection", "value": $(".dataTables_filterColumnSelect").val() });
                 aoData.push({ "name": "filterColumn", "value": searchFilter });
                 aoData.push({ "name": "websiteId", "value": "70005" });
                 aoData.push({ "name": "categoryId", "value": null });

                 $.ajax({
                     "dataType": 'json',
                     "type": "GET",
                     "cache": false,
                     "url": sSource,
                     "data": aoData,
                     "success": function (msg) {
                         var json = $.evalJSON(msg.d);
                         fnCallback(json);
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a onclick event handler function like this :

```
// Init you dataTable
[...]

// Bind onclik event
oArticleListTable.on('click', 'tr', function() {
    // Get first <td> id of the clicked row
    var firstColumnId = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').attr('id');
});
```

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5X8q/2/) (this is a simple dataTable initialisation, but it will work the same way)

**EDIT**

To add hover effect on row, just add the css class `hover` on the `<table>` element.

To identify selected row, you can use the `selected` css class in the click handler function :

```
oArticleListTable.on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var selectedRow = $(this);

    // Get first <td> id of the clicked row
    var firstColumnId = selectedRow.find('td:eq(0)').attr('id');

    // Manage selection style
    oArticleListTable.find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); // remove selection style on other row
    selectedRow.toggleClass('selected'); // change selected row style
});
```

I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5X8q/2/) to reflect changes

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how do you also highlight (select) the row?